# Use of monad >>= when variable is in the middle of a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hello there here is my issue.
This is my running code, which is fine:

```
showBalls = do
      howMany <- getInt
      return . take HowMany $ repeat 9
```

where my getInt does several checks in order to retrieve user input Int. However, my question is, is there a way to rewrite this part of code with the use of monads?

My aim is to use >>= and have a final one-line functions such as:

```
showBalls = fmap (take <$> (repeat 9)) getLine
```

however it doesnt work (as expected).
Any suggestion?

Comment: One line doesn't mean better. Also, that part of the code already uses monads.

Comment: Yep yep, I perfectly understand. It is not about what's better, it is about understanding the language I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flip` to reverse the arguments of `take`, which makes it possible to apply `repeat 9` to it and get function:

```
> :t flip take (repeat 9)
flip take (repeat 9) :: Num a => Int -> [a]
```

To use `>>=` with `getInt` we need `Int -> IO a` function:

```
> :t (getInt >>=)
(getInt >>=) :: (Int -> IO b) -> IO b
```

To get that, compose with `return` (it's `m [a]` because it will work for every monad, but is also restricted to lists; from the above type, `m` becomes `IO` and `b` becomes `[a]`):

```
> :t return . flip take (repeat 9)
return . flip take (repeat 9) :: (Monad m, Num a) => Int -> m [a]
```

The final expression is:

```
> :t getInt >>= return . flip take (repeat 9)
getInt >>= return . flip take (repeat 9) :: Num a => IO [a]
```

But, as I mentioned, I'm not really convinced it's strictly better than the original. As a more useful bit of knowledge, playing around with expressions and their types in GHCi is a good way of inventing transformations like that.

Comment: Or, since `x >>= return . f` is `fmap f x` or `f <$> x`, this can be further simplified to `flip take (repeat 9) <$> getInt`

Comment: you meant `fmap take (repeat 9) <$> getInt`?

Comment: @haskellguy: no, `flip` is correct. The `<$>` is already doing the `fmap`.

Answer (score 2):

I got it my self too but using lambda notation :)

```
showBalls = getInt >>= (\a -> return . take a $ repeat 9 )
```

Comment: This version with the lambda is actually exactly what do notation dessugars into. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad#Special_notation

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
showBalls = (liftM . flip take $ repeat 9) getInt
```

There is probably point free way to do it as well, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't type-check, it should be `$` instead of `.`

Comment: There's no way this composition makes sense: liftM's first argument is a function, not a list.

Comment: Maybe I wrote it in a confusing way.  liftM does get a function  : liftM . flip take

Comment: Welp, nevermind, I tested something else. Damn you, operator precedence.